# Possible to set mouse cursor during NativeDragDrop operation?

Tags: apache-flex, air, drag-and-drop

In an AIR app, I am trying to implement a tab interface like the one in Firefox or Chrome where you can drag a tab and create a new window from it. All goes well except when I drag the mouse out of my application over the (Windows) OS, **the mouse cursor indicates that the system will not accept the drop operation**. It shows something like this: http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/42419/16/denied_icon

It is technically not a problem as my app will still receive a `nativeDragComplete` event but is bad for user experience. What I would like to achieve is to show a normal mouse pointer and display a drag indicator next to it, like browsers do. **Can I somehow force the NativeDragManager not to show the denied icon?**

I've tried playing with various clipboard formats as it seems to be influencing the mouse pointer but couldn't find a complete solution to this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is not achievable using the NativeDragManager - the correct way is to implement custom drag drop behavior using lightweight Windows as described [here](http://codingangry.com/index.php/site/article/drag_drop_windows/).